# Solution to some finite sum of reciprocals of odd integers (continuation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Following the question I posted on [Solution to some finite sum of reciprocals of odd integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570133/solution-to-some-finite-sum-of-reciprocals-of-odd-integers), and the suggestion proposed by @Peter, let it be $S=\{O_1,O_2,...O_n\}$ a set of an odd number of distinct odd integers, and $O_j\notin S$ such that $O_j>3$.

I want to prove (or disprove) that it does not exist any solution such that $$\frac{O_j-2}{O_j} = \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{O_k}}$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a greedy algorithm, just fixing $O_j=5$ and repeatedly subtracting the largest value of the form $\frac{1}n$ for odd $n\neq 5$, one finds:
$$3/5 =  1/3 + 1/7 + 1/9 + 1/79 + 1/24885$$
One also gets
$$5/7 = 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/315$$
by the same means. I do not know if this process always works - the usual argument that the greedy algorithm for [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions) works doesn't apply here due to the restriction to odd denominators. It does seem like this greedy algorithm can represent all fractions with odd denominators, though - I wrote some code to generate such representations and it has handled everything I've tried. It appears that this more general negation of the question you ask about [is an open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_greedy_expansion). However, apparently, if you are more clever, you can express fraction with an odd denominator as a sum of reciprocals of odd denominators; the linked Wikipedia page briefly describes this.

Comment: Thanks @MiloBrandt, nice answer!!